# Reassemble crypto hmac code in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js

I am trying to reassemble code in C# from JavaScript, Node js code.

I wrote fully working example in Node just to find out if the code is working correctly but now i am having problems with finding equivalent functions in C#.

JavaScript code using Node.js.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var timestamp = Date.now() / 1000;
var what = timestamp + "hello";
var secret = "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ="; 
var key = Buffer(secret, 'base64');
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);

hmac.update(what);
var t = hmac.digest('base64');    
console.log(t);
```

I am only in need of knowing how to reassemble those functions:

```
var key = Buffer(secret, 'base64');
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);

hmac.update(what);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a c# example.  It includes a function.  You would pass your timestamp info as the string I assume, but it can be done with any string.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/eAZGfE

```
public static string HashString(string StringToHash, string HachKey)
{
    System.Text.UTF8Encoding myEncoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] Key = myEncoder.GetBytes(HachKey);
    byte[] Text = myEncoder.GetBytes(StringToHash);
    System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 myHMACSHA1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(Key);
    byte[] HashCode = myHMACSHA1.ComputeHash(Text);
    string hash =  BitConverter.ToString(HashCode).Replace("-", "");
    return hash.ToLower();
}
```

Comment: Please post your code inline; if the link ever goes dead this answer is useless as currently written.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but in case it's of any utility - I stumbled upon an exact same problem, and the solution above gave incorrect results. Here's what worked for me:

```
using var hmacSha256 = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
var hmac = hmacSha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
string token = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac);
```